# Render CGBitmapContext to UIScrollView

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, uiscrollview, ios9

I basically need to display an image from a `CGBitmapContext` in a `UIScrollView`. The final goal is to have the image rendered and allow for zoom, scrolling and updated at any scale/offset. So far, I've tried this using a `UIImageView`:

```
this.Image = new UIImage(this.bmpContext.ToImage()); // "this" being the UIImageView
```

This simply doesn't render anything, but I might just be missing something. An other technique I've tried is using the current context inside the `Draw(CGRect)` call of my `UIView` (not `UIImageView` here):

```
using (CGImage image = this.bmpContext.ToImage())
{
    CGContext context = UIGraphics.GetCurrentContext();
    context.SaveState();

    context.InterpolationQuality = CGInterpolationQuality.High;

    //Translate and flip vertically to render in the right orientation
    context.TranslateCTM(0, this.Frame.Height);
    context.ScaleCTM(1.0f,-1.0f);

    context.DrawImage(this.Frame, image);

    context.RestoreState();
}
```

This partially works. It renders correctly at a scale of 1:1, but doesn't render at (0,0) as expected, and smaller than the size expected.

I feel like there has to be a simpler way to do this, I simply want to display the image in the `UIScrollView` and be able to move around, pinch zoom and update the view at any time. Is there a way to achieve this? Would it be simpler to draw directly inside a `UIView` and forget about the `UIImageView`?

UPDATE:

I got something here, I use the image size to translate and draw it. It's more consistent than the bounds or the frame. Here what I've got:

```
using (CGImage image = this.bmpContext.ToImage())
{
    CGContext context = UIGraphics.GetCurrentContext();
    context.SaveState();

    context.InterpolationQuality = CGInterpolationQuality.High;

    //Translate and flip vertically to render in the right orientation
    context.TranslateCTM(0, image.Height);
    context.ScaleCTM(1, -1);

    context.DrawImage(new CGRect(0, 0, image.Width, image.Height), image);

    context.RestoreState();
}
```

Now, This renders properly the first time I draw, but then if I render again, It only updates a portion of the screen.

- At a scale of 1:1, everything looks fine
- At a scale of 1:2 (zoomed out, smaller), it only updates about 50% of the screen (0, 0, width / 2, height / 2)
- At a scale of 3:4, it's about 75% too.

The thing is, the image is rendered at the proper size, but is clipped by some sort of a rectangle that iOS thinks I should be limited to. Is there something I'm missing here? I tried to expand it, but it really seems to be stuck there and I can't enlarge it. At least I haven't succeeded to do so!